# What's the proper way to use 先 versus 前に or 以前?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I'm trying to understand why 先 is not the best choice to use in these sentences. Is it wrong to use it in this way?

×　先、学校で何かが起こった。
○　以前、学校で何かが起こった。

×　先の書いた本から十年間が過ぎました。
○　前に書いた本から十年間が過ぎました。

Comment: Although this is not the point of your question, “先に書いた本” is perfectly acceptable, although this phrase somehow suggests to me that the speaker had planned to write at least two books from the beginning (this might not be agreed by all speakers of Japanese).  “先の書いた本” is incorrect as Ignacio explained.

Comment: @Louis: Actually, could you specify whether you mean 先 as in さき (as in さきに) or さっき (as in さっきから) because I'm not quite so sure anymore.

Comment: @Matti: I'm not sure either, I just learned about さっき from you. I meant it like "Earlier, something happened at school" and "Ten years have past since the last book was written". Forgive the passive transformation in the second translation.

Comment: @Louis: In their own way, they both mean "earlier". さっき means "just a while ago" while さき is used when talking about the order of events (it means "before something else")

Comment: Ah, got it! That makes sense now. For the first example I meant さっき and for the second さき. I assumed さき fulfilled both meanings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean 先 as in さっき. It's usually written in hiragana to avoid confusion.

I think the first sentences are just fine. The × one sounds like spoken language and ○ one sounds more like written language.

In the second × sentence, though, さっき would not work because it's used for things that happened "just now" and ten years ago is not "just now". Also, the の there is not correct, it's only used when さっき is used to modify a noun or a noun-phrase. You could say e.g.「さっき書いたメール」 for "an e-mail [I] wrote just now" though.

Comment: Thank you Matti, I'll be careful about the hiragana. About the さっきの, doesn't 書いた本 become a noun?

Comment: @Louis, I think I understand what you're getting at. さっきの本 means 'the book from before'. So it is theoretically possible to parse the さっきの書いた本 as 'the book from before, which *sby* wrote'. However, it is more natural to assume that the さっき refers to the act of writing, in which case it would be さっき書いた本. This doesn't make much sense either, though, since さっき means just a few moments ago. If you just *finished* writing a book a few moments ago, you could say さっき書き終えた本.

Comment: *さっき is usually written in hiragana to avoid confusion*? Does it mean you believe there is an other way to write it? Which would be ?

Comment: @oldergod: Dictionaries (and I assume that's where OP got his thing) list 先 as the kanji for さっき, so I guess by the most lenient definition of "acceptable writing" you could use 先, but in practice nobody does.

Comment: @oldergod I thought 先 = さき. Am I wrong?

Comment: @dotnetN00b That is correct. I never saw 先 meaning さっき and viceversa. That is why I got confused when M.Virkkunen said that 先 could mean さっき.

Comment: Can we assume  さっき or  さき can be used interchangeably in this answer?

Comment: @Aki I don't know how the dictionaries define it, but I was corrected unanimously by native speakers when I tried to use 先 (ahead)　to mean さっき (just now) on Lang-8. So I'm convinced that, at least in modern usage, the two have very different meanings.